# An alternative cursor template

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I recently stumbled on the following cursor implementation:

```
open cursor
while 1=1
begin
    fetch next
    if @@fetch_status <> 0 break
   
    (cursor logic here)

end
```

This seems cleaner to me that the template code one can see everywhere which includes two of the same FETCHes:

```
open cursor
fetch next
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    (cursor logic here)
    fetch next
end
```

Is there any advantage to the second writing?

Comment: I agree... first seems better.

Comment: I do not agree. Sure, both can be read and understood, but the first example seems contrived and introduces "fake" logic (WHILE 1 = 1) - it starts with an endless loop - this logic does not arise naturally.
Second version - each step describes itself, whether taken as a whole or in isolation.

Comment: Asking for cursor "better" implementation seems funny to me. A cursor is something you should strive to avoid using, as it's almost never the best course of action.  Having said that, I don't think there's much difference between the two options. Both seems reasonably readable - so consistency is the key IMHO.  Try to avoid cursors, but if you must, choose one pattern and use only it.